# SQL - JOIN last child

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do some custom filtering. I need to JOIN latest child post_author. This doesn't seem to work well, it keeps returning wrong childs:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT MAX(ID) as child_ID, post_parent, post_author as child_post_author FROM wp_posts 
         WHERE post_type = 'ticket_reply'
         GROUP BY post_parent
         ) sl ON wp_posts.ID = sl.post_parent
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
SELECT child_ID, posts.post_author, wp1.post_author FROM wp_posts posts
LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT MAX(ID) as child_ID, post_parent FROM wp_posts 
         WHERE post_type = 'ticket_reply'
         GROUP BY post_parent
         ) sl ON posts.ID = sl.post_parent
INNER JOIN wp_posts wp1 on sl.child_ID = wp1.ID
WHERE posts.ID = 1499
```

Comment: If you can't confirm that this is working, then please use it as [edit] on your question and delete the answer. Thanks.